The common closure of two metric spaces is also the closure of their intersection
$(X_1,d_1), (X_2, d_2)$ are two metric space, $V\subset X_1\cap X_2$ is dense in $(X_1,d_1)$, and dense in $(X_2,d_2)$. Prove that $V$ is dense in $(X_1\cap X_2 ,d_1+d_2)$.
My attempt: For each $x\in X_1\cap X_2$, I try two find two sequence $\{u_m\}$ and $\{v_m\}$ such that $d_1(u_m,x)\to 0$ and $d_2(v_m,x)\to 0$. Then for every $k$, I take subsequence such that $d_1(u_{m_k},x)<\frac1k, d_2(v_{m_k},x)<\frac1k$. Then if I can also conclude that $d_2(u_{m_k},x)$ and $d_1(v_{m_k},x)$ are also small, I can take element from $B(u_{m_k},\frac1k)\cap B(v_{m_k},\frac1k)\cap V$. But I have trouble verifying this.

Yes, you can prove this by sequences, but that is really the hard way to go about it. A better approach is to consider that a set $A$ is dense in a metric space $(X, d)$ if and only if every open ball in $X$ contains an element of $A$.
